# How to Schedule Windows Service Daily once at 11AM

Tags: c#

Im running the windows service  which checks whether time is greater than 11Am and if no record is present for that particular report type on that  date then data is inserted. Timer is scheduled for every 10 minutes. Is there any other Alternative, as i feel there  is too much of database hit.

It Checks the EmailNotificationSentlog table and if no record exists for that date and for that reporttype, data is inserted.

> ```
> Sno   ReportType  CreatedDate
> 1     Daily        2015-05-29 11:00:07.683
> 2     Daily        2015-06-01 11:00:08.317
> 3     Daily        2015-06-02 11:17:56.890
> ```

Procedure to Check whether data is inserted or not.

```
    CreatePROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_get_EmailNotificationSentLogExists]     
    (    
     @RptType nvarchar(50)    
    )    
    AS    
    BEGIN    
     Declare @Time nvarchar(50)    
     Declare @RetVal int     
     set @RetVal = 0    
     Set @Time = '11:00'    

     IF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 114) >= @Time)    
     BEGIN    
        IF not exists(select 1 from EmailnotificationSentLog where ltrim(rtrim(ReportType)) = @RptType    
      and  convert(date,CreatedDate) = convert(date,GETDATE()))    
     BEGIN       
      SET @RetVal = 1    
        END    
     END    
     select @RetVal    

    END
```

Procedure to Insert record

```
CreatePROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Insert_EmailNotificationSentLog]  
(  
 @RptType nvarchar(50)  
)  
AS  
BEGIN  
IF NOT EXISTS( select 1 from EmailNotificationSentLog where ReportType = @RptType 
    and cast(createddate as date) = CAST(getdate() as date))
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO EmailNotificationSentLog(ReportType,CreatedDate)values (@RptType,getdate()) 
END 
END
```

Service Class:

```
        public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
        {
            Timer timer1 = new Timer();
            SqlConnection objSqlCon = new  SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SqlConnection"].ToString());
            string objRetval = string.Empty;
            public Service1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

            timer1.Interval = 600000; //10 mts
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            WriteLog("Test Windows Service");
        }
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender,ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            WriteLog("Test Job Done Sucessfully");
            // If Time greater than 11 and if record doesnt exists
            objRetval = RetrieveData(ReportType.Daily.ToString());
            if (objRetval == "1")
            {
                InsertData();
            }
            //OnStop();
        }
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            WriteLog("Test Job Stopped Sucessfully");
        }

        public string RetrieveData(string strRptType)
        {
            string strRetVal = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_get_EmailNotificationSentLogExists", objSqlCon);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RptType", strRptType);
                if (objSqlCon.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    objSqlCon.Open();
                }
                strRetVal = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                //l1.WriteLog("Data Inserted Successfully");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //l1.WriteLog(ex.Message.ToString());
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                objSqlCon.Close();
            }
            return strRetVal;
        }

        void InsertData()
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Insert_EmailNotificationSentLog", objSqlCon);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RptType", ReportType.Daily.ToString());
                if (objSqlCon.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    objSqlCon.Open();
                }
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                WriteLog("Data Inserted Successfully");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteLog(ex.Message.ToString());
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                objSqlCon.Close();
            }
        }

        public void WriteLog(string strMessage)
        {
            string strLogDir = string.Empty, strLogFileName = string.Empty, SstrFilePath = string.Empty;
            strLogDir = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogDirectory"].ToString();
            strLogFileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Logname"].ToString();
            if (!Directory.Exists(strLogDir))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(strLogDir);
            }
            SstrFilePath = strLogDir + "\\" + strLogFileName;
            if (!File.Exists(SstrFilePath))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(SstrFilePath))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("================================================================================");
                    sw.WriteLine(" // " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                    sw.WriteLine("Message \t\t\t: " + strMessage);
                    sw.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                StreamReader sReder = new StreamReader(SstrFilePath);
                string oldText = sReder.ReadToEnd();
                sReder.Close();
                StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(SstrFilePath);
                sWriter.WriteLine(oldText);
                sWriter.WriteLine("================================================================================");
                sWriter.WriteLine(" // " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                sWriter.WriteLine("File Name \t\t\t: " + strMessage);
                sWriter.Close();
            }
        }

        enum ReportType {Daily,Monthly,Yearly}

    }
```

Comment: As wherby hinted at below, a Windows service is probably not what you need.  Rather a standard program that is kicked off by a scheduled task is more fitting.

Answer (score 0):

In windows you don't need manual check time to run a task, there is task schedular for you to use:

```
Open Task Scheduler by clicking the Start button , clicking Control Panel, clicking System and Security, clicking Administrative Tools, and then double-clicking Task Scheduler.‌   If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

Click the Action menu, and then click Create Basic Task.

Type a name for the task and an optional description, and then click Next.

Do one of the following:

To select a schedule based on the calendar, click Daily, Weekly, Monthly, or One time, click Next; specify the schedule you want to use, and then click Next.

To select a schedule based on common recurring events, click When the computer starts or When I log on, and then click Next.

To select a schedule based on specific events, click When a specific event is logged, click Next; specify the event log and other information using the drop-down lists, and then click Next.

To schedule a program to start automatically, click Start a program, and then click Next.

Click Browse to find the program you want to start, and then click Next.

Click Finish.
```

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7

Comment: When Scheduler runs the service error message is popped  ie  cannot start service from the command line or a debugger.A windows service must be installed(using installutil.exe) and then started with serverexplorer,windows services administrative tool or the net start command. ive already installed the service using C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe  installutil.exe

Comment: Im stuck can anyone help me please?